# How can I autostart Albert?

Tags: linux, autostart, albert

Since I want albert to be always running, I want albert to start on desktop login.

How can I make albert start itself on login?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the moment there is no autostart option, since this application is meant to be desktop agnostic and there is no standard way to achieve this. Fortunately there is a standard way for most Linux/Unix system (those adhering the FreeDesktop standards). However, since the app is meant to become cross platform in future, the option is not available in the app, but has to be setup by the user.

The [XDG Desktop Application Autostart Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/autostart-spec-latest.html) specifies which/how apps should be started by the desktop environments on login. The most intuitive way to achieve this is the autostart dialog of your desktop environment, which implements the rules in the spec above, the fastest to simply link the [desktop entry](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/) of the app to the [autostart directory](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/autostart-spec-latest.html#idm46332582893872):

```
ln -s /usr/share/applications/albert.desktop ~/.config/autostart/
```

<sub>Note: I am the author of this app. This Q&A is part of the migration of the FAQ to the public.</sub>